# Spring boot custom logic for 500 errors

Tags: spring-boot

In Spring Boot, how do I add extra server logic that runs for any 500 error? I don't want to change the *circumstances* under which a 500 error is returned; I just would like to add some extra processing to capture some crash information when a 500 does happen.

I've tried `@ExceptionHandler` and similar, but can't seem to add a handler for "anything that would generate a 500". In my searching, I can only seem to find articles describing how to change which exceptions *produce* a 500 error, not to change what happens when a 500 error occurs.

Comment: Because 500 is a HTTP representation of uncaught exceptions in your flow. So you should simply use an @ExceptionHandler für Exception.class and then handle it accordingly.

Comment: @jAC that is simply not true, there are plenty of well defined exceptions that will return a 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR you can see some here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.java

Comment: what i would do is to instead write a filter that will intercept all responses that contain a HttpStatus 500 and then do your logging in the filter.

Comment: @Toerktumlare - ah, that could work. Though I wouldn't still have the exception on hand to capture its stack trace I think?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution I arrived at. I'm not sure it's the "right" answer but it appears to be working.

(The suggestion from @Toerktumlare to use a filter was a good one, though in my case, the "crash information" I wanted included an exception stack trace, which isn't available in a filter.)

What I've done is add two `@ExceptionHandler` methods in a `@ControllerAdvice` class.

The first method handles `ResponseStatusException`, which are expressly intended to indicate specific HTTP status codes. This is the superclass of about a dozen built-in exceptions that Spring creates. I treat the exception as a "crash" and collect extra info if the code is 500:

```
@ExceptionHandler({ResponseStatusException.class})
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleResponseStatusException(ResponseStatusException ex, WebRequest request) {
    if (ex.getStatus() == INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR) {
        return handleCrash(ex, request);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.toString(), responseHeaders(), status);
    }
}

private static HttpHeaders responseHeaders() {
    HttpHeaders result = new HttpHeaders();
    result.setContentType(TEXT_PLAIN);
    return result;
}
```

The second method is a fallback for other exceptions that are not already handled by other handlers:

```
@ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMiscellaneousServerError(Throwable ex, WebRequest request) {
    return handleCrash(ex, request);
}
```

This will have the effect of turning all other exceptions into 500 errors. I haven't yet lived with this solution long enough to know whether this is ok.